# Showing Different Modes of Editor According to User Roles

Tags: dotnetnuke

Is there any way that I can show different modes of an editor (minimal, full, etc.) to users according to their roles? It's doesn't make difference for me to use Rad Editor or Ckeditor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the default providers, only FCKEditor supports customizing the toolbar by role. With Rad Editor, you can use [dnnWerk RadEditor Provider](http://radeditor.codeplex.com/).

**Instructions for FCKEditor [(from seablick.com)](http://seablick.com/blog/101/customizing-fckeditor-toolbars.aspx)**

1. Define toolbars in `\Providers\HtmlEditorProviders\Fck\Custom\fckconfig.js`
2. Open the custom editor options popup
   [image: Show custom editor options]
3. Select settings type (Instance/Module/Portal)
4. Set toolbar visibility for different roles
5. Apply the custom settings to Instance/Module/Portal. (Default value is the same as the "Settings type", but I'm not sure if these settings have different effects, or is it only the "Apply to" dropdown that counts.)

[image]

#### See also

> [Customizing FCKeditor Toolbars](http://seablick.com/blog/101/customizing-fckeditor-toolbars.aspx)